# Foreach a list or which would be the correct approach?

Tags: c#, list, .net-4.0

I have a `List<Player>` that I wish to output ordered to a string, so I am wondering what would be the correct way of doing this and if a simple foreach will always output it ordered already (so far it does from the tests I did) ?

For example:

```
int position = 0;
foreach (var player in list)
{
    position++;
    Console.Write(position.ToString() + " " + player.Name);
}
```

Where I could possible later get it like `list[X]` where X is the player number in the list.

Or are there better ways of doing this ?

Comment: Your approach should work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A List will output the elements in the order they were added to the list.  If you using .net 3.0+ you can execute an `.OrderBy(r=> r.Foo)` to guarantee the order prior to printing the output.  if your going to be incrementing a counter during your loop, I would suggest using a classic for loop as opposed to a foreach

```
for(int pos =0; pos<list.count; ++pos) {
  Console.Write(pos.ToString() + " " + list[pos].Name);
}
```

Comment: Is the list indexer guaranteed to be constant time?

Comment: the list won't be changed at the time I need to output it so I guess yes it will be constant, thanks for the reply I totally forgot about the for ;) which does make a lot more sense then what I was doing.

Comment: @Prix the list can be constant, but that doesn't mean that the indexer is constant time.  For example, if the list is implemented by stepping through each element, then accessing `list[1000]` will require 1000 steps (which is not constant time).  For a standard array, `list[1000]` is at a known location, so the operation is constant time.  If it takes many operations to access a later element in the list, then the for loop is much slower than the foreach

Comment: @Foo Bah I am a bit confused by your usage of the term constant but are you saying a list of unknown size against a list of a known size in short ?

Comment: @Prix Take a linked list (stl list), for example.  In order to get the 1000th element from a linked list, you have to start from the first element and walk 1000 elements.  That takes at least 1000 operations.  On the other hand, for a normal array, you can calculate exactly where the 1000th element will lie.  Thus, you dont have to walk through every element, and it takes the same amount of time to get `list[1000]` as it does to get `list[100]`

Answer (score 1):

For a list, using foreach will always output in the original order of the list.

Answer (score 1):

What you have works. List is an ordered collection and its enumerator is also ordered. This is a good question to ask because not all collections have a concept of ordering, such as a Dictionary

Comment: pickles, that is true but a dictionary relies mainly on it's key and I was not sure that the list had some sort of ordering :) I was looking in the getenumerator function but was still a bit in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

If by ordered you mean in the order in which it in the collection that your foreach is exactly how I would do it. However, if you need to change the order then you might think about using LINQ, especially if you might want to order by different properties of the plyer class.